# How to draw line slowly from a point to another point in P5?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am using p5.js to draw a simple line.

```js
function setup() {
  //createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  createCanvas(400, 200);
}

function draw() {
  background(255, 255, 255);
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  stroke(255, 0, 0);
  strokeWeight(1);
  line(0, 0, 250, 100);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.js"></script>
```

But the line drawn suddenly at once.
How can I draw the line slowly / gradually? (i.e in 300 milliseconds).
That it looks like animating from point(0,0) to point(250,100).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a quick look at p5 and it looks like it calls the `draw` method at intervals. If you want movement to happen you just need to program it.

I've put together a quick example below. I think it's drawing a lot slower than you want but I'm not sure how often p5 calls `draw`.

```js
var position = 0,
  end = 300;

function setup() {
  //createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  createCanvas(400, 200);
}

function draw() {
  background(255, 255, 255);
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  stroke(255, 0, 0);
  strokeWeight(1);

  var xEnd = 250,
    yEnd = 100;

  // Got to the end yet?
  if (position < end) {
    
    // Work out positions.
    xEnd = (xEnd / end) * position;
    yEnd = (yEnd / end) * position;
  }

  line(0, 0, xEnd, yEnd);
  
  // Increment position.
  position++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[FrameRate](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/frameRate) can be used to adjust the speed of a drawing. This sketch draws a diagonal line that begins slowly at point 0,0 and then speeds up until it reaches point 250, 100.

```js
var x = 0;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 200);
  frameRate(10);
}

function draw() {
    background(255, 255, 255);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    strokeWeight(1);
    // y = mx + b
    line(0, 0, x, 100/250*x);
    x++;
    if (x > 50){
      frameRate(30);
    }
    if (x > 250){
      noLoop();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```